# Prevent resource data to trigger $watch (Angular.js)

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of item with a quantity, some of them already have an quantity that is retrieve from a resource when the page loads. Then I watch that same field for any changes made by the user to be able to auto-save theses changes. The autosaving process works pretty well, but the thing is that watch is triggered when the quantity gets filed by the ressource and I would prefer not because it's just silly to put that information back to the server.

How would you do that? :)

```
app.controller('InventoryLineController', function($scope, inventoryService){
  // Populate les champs de lignes déjà enregistrés sur le serveur.
  inventoryService.getLine($scope.inventory, $scope.product).$promise.then(function(inventoryLine){
    $scope.quantity = inventoryLine.quantity;
  });

  // Sauvegarde automatique lors du changement de quantité.
  $scope.$watch('quantity', function(newVal, oldVal){
      console.log(newVal); // VALIDATIONS + CALL TO SAVE METHOD
  });
});
```

Here's the html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="product in productList" ng-controller='InventoryLineController'>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" name="quantity" value="{{quantity}}" min="0" smartFloat ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-model="quantity">
</tr>
```

Thank's!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to store a response from the resource separately, and use it to compare against a newVal if it is changed or not. For example:

```
app.controller('InventoryLineController', function($scope, inventoryService){
  var savedObj = {};

  // Populate les champs de lignes déjà enregistrés sur le serveur.
  inventoryService.getLine($scope.inventory, $scope.product).$promise.then(function(inventoryLine){
    savedObj = inventoryLine;
    $scope.quantity = inventoryLine.quantity;
  });

  // Sauvegarde automatique lors du changement de quantité.
  $scope.$watch('quantity', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (angular.equals(newVal, savedObj.quantity)) {
      return;
    }

    savedObj.quantity = newVal;
    console.log(newVal); // VALIDATIONS + CALL TO SAVE METHOD
  });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can ignore newval if its equal to old val

```
   $scope.$watch('quantity', function(newVal, oldVal){
     if(newVal !== oldVal) {
        console.log(newVal); // VALIDATIONS + CALL TO SAVE METHOD
     }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work, because at that time, oldVal is undefined. And I just can't ignore change if oldVal is undefined because I won't be able to save changes made by the user

Comment: Yes, just like they are different when $watch get triggered by the data provided by the resource.

Comment: But what's going to the server and what's coming back from the server must be same, I thought

Comment: Because input provided by the user won't be undefined when it's going from save

Comment: OldVal would be undefined for some inputs when the user will input a value because they dont all get value at the start.

Comment: Would it be possible to make sure that the "$watch" thinghy enter in service after the inputs get their values from the resource?